# How to identify a Google user account by JWT?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api, jwt, google-oauth, google-signin

I have a flutter Android app which implements Google sign in, and ASP.NET core Web API server, which using token-based authentication. Android app sends jwt token to server, which contains such information as email, username etc. So on server. I need a parameter, on which user can be authorized.

Does Google's JWT contains any information, which is unique for every account?

If jwt does not, is it possible to get a unique identifier after validating this token using `GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(token)`?